# Delegation with forms in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a system, where I am loading forms via Ajax into a predefined container. After the form has been loaded, delegate is attached to input boxes and submit event, so that a validate function is launched. Within this validate function a `$.post()` method is used to check if the values input in the form are correct.

I want to check if the `$.post()` returned an empty json string, so that I could return `true` to the function that delegated the event, so that I could submit the form to the server, and reload the content for that container. I am using the function in [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217238/unable-to-set-variable-inside-a-post-function) to get the validation data back, but I can't seem to figure out a way, to return `false` or `true` to the delegating function. Any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your latest code, including the delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   async:false
 });
```

This makes the `ajax` request into `sjax`, if I may say so, and therefore the code i wanted to use, works.